# Align table in div background

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to align a table in a div background, and must be responsive.

This is what i want:
[image]

EDIT:
I want to put the table on the dark-blue background of the image, and always must be there, doesn't matter the resolution, so must be responsive

This is the table css

```
.tg {
  color: white;
  width: 485px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 109px;
  left: 266px;
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  height: 336px;
}
```

And this there is the code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0nxxuw2/)

Please help!

Answer (score -1):

Try this, this is what I understood 
Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k0nxxuw2/4/

Code changed:

Updated

```
    .tg {
        color: white;
        width: 485px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 109px;
        left: 266px;
        top: auto;
        right: auto;
        height: 336px;
}
```

With

```
.tg {
    color: white;
    width: 485px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 109px;
    left: 266px;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    height: 336px;
    padding-top:200px
}
```

Comment: So that error message you got about not just pasting a link to jquery is there for a reason...

Comment: It's not ok. I want to put that table on the dark-blue background of the image, and always must be there, doesn't matter the resolution, so must be responsive.